# How to access a file from one another file in nodejs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the below project structure. I am trying to access db.js inside CategoryController.js.

[image]

I have used the code below.

```
var db = require('./../routes/db');
```

when I'm trying to run the Node.js project using npm start it is showing the error below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below

```
var db = require('./../db.js');
```

as the `db.js` file is just out of controllers folder

Comment: can you explain me what is single dot(.) and waht is double (..)

Comment: @SangramBadi the single dot(.) means in the current directory while the double dot(..) means jumping in the parent directory

Comment: tank you for your reply